# Is there a way to indicate in linked data that one page supersedes another?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have a page that supersedes another page: two blog post presented early versions of an idea, but now that idea is further developed in a more archival document that has its own page.

Is there a way to indicate in my linked data (currently using JSON-LD) that the new page should be considered a more current substitute for the original page? I have updated the older pages with in-text links pointing to the new one, but would like to also express this semantically.

Comment: 1) As you say linked data, does that imply that you are fine with any vocabulary? Or does it have to be Schema.org? 2) Do you really ask about a general linked data context, or do you only look for a solution that search engines support?

Comment: Even if you found JSON-LD that  indicated this, browsers and search engines wouldn't pay any attention to it.

Comment: What is the goal of marking up the structured data in this way?

Comment: I'm looking for a search-engine-supported solution. My goal is to give search engines a hint to favor the superseding page (which is on the same domain).